# Web service; There was an error generating the XML document ---> The type System.__ComObject was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

There were no problems before but now when Im trying to connect to db using web service connection succeeds and after that I get error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.__ComObject was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

The problem is I cant use XmlInclude with System.__ComObject cause its private.

web method:

```
    private dynamic connect;
    [WebMethod]
    public dynamic GetConnect()
    {
        var machineName = Environment.MachineName;
        if (connect != null)
        {
            return connect;
        }

        var comConnector = new COMConnector();
        comConnector.PoolTimeout = 10;

        connect = comConnector.Connect(connectionString);

        return connect;
```

error trace:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.__ComObject was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
> in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
> in Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
> in Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write14_anyType(Object o)
> in Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ObjectSerializer.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)
> in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
> in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
> in  System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
> in System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)
> in System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues)
> in System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

Comment: Why is your web service returning `dynamic`?

Comment: Why are you trying to return a COMConnector? Http only supports text / binary streams. You can't just return some proxy to a 3rd party COM component.

Comment: webmetod getconnect() used by other web metods in this web service, for example in searchrow() which searchs row in db using 'dymanic' comconnector returned by getconnect() and searchrow() returns string

Comment: few days ago getconnect() worked fine and returned <GetConnectResponse xmlns="http://WebService.org/">
      <GetConnectResult />
    </GetConnectResponse>. If I run web service localy all methods but getconnect() works but if I host web service on server and try to connect from client it crash giving the described error

Comment: 1) It makes zero sense for a web server to return references to a COM object. 2) Even if you could return the object to a client invoking it will most likely fail during subsequent interaction. COM and particularly DCOM use named pipes something that works terribly over a WAN 3) If you are super keen on COM over a network look into DCOM...but _thar be dragons_

Comment: I know it's not a good idea to return the com object, but it's not my code, although this way was probably the lesser of two evils, which worked for a long time and now crashes at the creation of the xml

Comment: _An app that suddenly breaks because it was using an **undocumented API** call now since removed, doesn't mean the app's code was correct in the first place._  Just like undocumentated API calls, web servers that return **COM objects** are possible examples of _poor design decisions_.

Comment: The error sound like you have a base class and inherited classes.  With xml, the inherited classes have a 'type' attribute that is put into the xml to differentiate between the base type and the inherited type.  The error message is saying to use xmlinclude.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0